# keypress arrows down not working

Tags: javascript

event on keypress arrows down not working, not changing color to red, no errors at console, What i'm doing wrong?

```
 var getText = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];

            getText.onclick = function() {
                    getText.innerHTML = "Simple";
            }

              function keyPress() {
                if(event.which == 13) { 
                    getText.style.color = 'blue';
                }

                if(event.which == 40) {
                    getText.style.color = 'red';
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your code is missing some part... Where does the `event` variable gets set? I don't see you listening to the keypress event either.

Comment: Also, arrow keys are usually not triggering the keypress event... But I'll give more details about all this once I see your real case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Salketer noted you need an event listener to observe keyboard events. The `keyPress` function could be used as event handler in that case. (But `event` must be set as the first argument in the function definition.)

```
var getText = document.getElementsByTagName( 'h1' )[0];

function keyPress( event ) {
    if(event.which == 13) { 
        getText.style.color = 'blue';
    }

    if(event.which == 40) {
        getText.style.color = 'red';
    }
}

/* Setup an event listener and use keyPress as event handler */
window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keyPress, false );
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener